# Implementando e webService e Client em Java com Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou com dificuldades em implementar um webService em java com eclipse, 
algumas classes não foram geradas, porém elas estão listadas nos arquivos xsds, 
criei um documento no docs para explicar melhor.

Obrigado

Aqui https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qnZXa8URhgYFALP3swGs9ISgKBDZc9GyTrDguxJbM7g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Coloca esse conteudo do gDrive aqui... nós ajudamos a formatar...

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar utilize o `wsimport` no cmd.

Para você visualizar o help dele digite no cmd `wsimport -?`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As opções básicas que você pode utilizar são :

- `keep` (ele deixará os fontes salvos)
- `p` (para especificar um pacote específico. Ex.: br.com.teste)
- `d` (onde será criado os arquivos)

Importante: Caso o seu WSDL tenha autenticação (login e senha) você precisará criar um arquivo contendo o login e senha com a URL do WSDL e utilizar o `option -Xauthfile` com o caminho deste arquivo para a autenticação.

Exemplo do conteúdo do arquivo: https://username:password@www.example.com

Comment: Valeu, funcionou. Desculpe a demora!!